# Pass Pointer to Array Element to Function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a program for a task in Linear Algebra that performs computations on vectors and matrices of floating point numbers.

i.e.,

```
v = [3.14159, 2.256, 1.5783, 6.782]

A = [   9.7     2.333    5.467   5.2123
        6.789   4.789   5.671   9.111
        1.113   4.562   8.223   5.2125
        6.666   7.8181  3.426   4.3567]
```

A part of the program performs the same operations on an input vector as it does on a specified row of an input matrix, handled by a function in C++. In C++, the same function can accept input of either a vector or matrix by having it accept a pointer to a specific  array element; as long as the pointer arithmetic is meticulous and, knowing memory layout is row-major, it works. I am wondering if the same can be done in JavaScript.

I could write either of two functions:

i) A function that expects a vector.
Passing the vector in works.
 
However, passing in the matrix doesn't work.
I had hoped to pass in the pointer to, say, the first element in the second row (the element containing 6.789). Then to access the entire row by something like A[0][i]. But JavaScript doesn't like that.

ii) A function that expects a matrix.
Passing the matrix in works.
However, passing in the vector doesn't work. If I try to access the vector elements as v[0][i], JavaScript doesn't like that.

Either my syntax is incorrect, or I am trying to do something that cannot be done.

The vector and array cannot be changed in form (i.e., flattened, etc.) because the rest of the program needs them to keep their forms; the vector needs to remain a vector and the matrix needs to remain a matrix.

In JavaScript, is it possible to pass a pointer to a specific array element into a function and then, within the function, have the vector (or row of matrix) treated as just a regular array?

If not, is there a suggested work-around?

Comment: You don't really have pointers in Javascript. You can always pass a specific variable into a function, perform your calculations and then return it and merge it back into the original array. Is that what you'd want to do?

Comment: @Keno That may be possible. Ideally, my goal is to write one function that can take as input either a matrix or vector--without impairing performance significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you're after?

```js
function doSomethingWithVectorOrMatrixRow(vectorOrMatrix, matrixRow) {
  const aVector = matrixRow === undefined ? vectorOrMatrix : vectorOrMatrix[matrixRow];
  return doSomething(aVector);
}
/* Use it as */ doSomethingWithVectorOrMatrixRow(v); 
/* or */        doSomethingWithVectorOrMatrixRow(A, 1);
```

---

Although of course it would be more efficient to store a matrix as a flat `Array`, and simply operate on a given range of that `Array`, which would work equally well for a vector (range = whole vector), but you say you can't change the data structure used.

Comment: Thanks. Nice suggestion. I suppose it would have been easier to have created the matrix as a vector in the first place, and access it via 1D referencing. i.e., _conceptually_, A may be a NROWS x NCOLS 2D matrix saved as a 1D array, and accessing element A[i][j] as A[i*NCOLS + j].To change it now would involve re-writing most of the program and many other sub-routines. I will work with your suggestion and see where it takes me.

Comment: If you have time, I would still suggest abstracting away the data structure the matrix is stored in, in the spirit of [refactoring mercilessly](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/refactor.html): You could create a `class Matrix { get(i, j) {} }`, then only the `get` method would need to change. You could also add a `getRow(j)` method, and of course a `set(i, j)` method

Comment: *I meant `set(i, j, v)`*